# ASP.NET Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime-format

- I'm having a problem with an application on a specific server.

**On every environment except the problem environment**

The server correctly recognizes that all clients are in the UK and parses UK formatted dates:

```
DD/MM/YYYY
```

**On the problem server**

The problem only appears to happen on one server. This server seems to incorrectly require american dates:

```
MM/DD/YYYY
```

**What I've tried already**

- Adding a "globalization" section to web.config file to attempt to force en-GB culture
- Checking the "machine.config's" globalization section (it says en-GB as well).
- I've checked that the clients are requesting en-GB as the prefered culture for the respnse.
- At Eoin's suggestion I've also checked the regional settings for the server (they have the date set to dd/MM/yyyy which is correct).

**What I cannot try**

I'm using MS ASP.NET MVC which is automatically de-serializing the HTML form data into an object, so I can't manually specify the date format -- e.g. using `DateTime.Parse(myDateStr, "dd/MM/yyyy")` as the parsing is done by Microsoft MVC.

Is there anything else I can do. This is an intranet app, and all clients are in the UK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to do following two things.

1. Set Culture in web.config as given below

   **uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB"** .
2. Set your form method to POST as I have mentioned below

   ```
   using (Html.BeginForm("DailyReport", "Reports", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ActivityReport" }))
   ```

**DailyReport** is your controller action method, **Reports** is controller and most important thing is  **FormMethod.Post** by setting form method to POST will solve your Date format problem.

Enjoy!

Comment: Indeed you are correct, setting the form to POST instead of GET resolves the problem. I can't work out why this would make a difference though...

Comment: see my comment below. data on the URI is culture invariant so that URIs have the same behavior for all users regardless of Culture.

Answer (score 5):

If you're overriding the current culture like that in your globalization section, make sure you specify the UICulture & Culture options.

However given that you've got this problem on only 1 out of many servers, I would expect that the server itself is configured differently. If you can log in to your problem-server as an admin, check the following (this is windows 7 but should be similar on Windows Server 2008)

Control Panel > Region & Language > Formats Tab > Format: "English (United Kingdom)"

and verify that the dates are expected in dd/MM/yyyy format

Comment: Thanks, I've checked the regional settings and they are set correctly for the UK (dd/MM/yyyy).

Comment: And you've tried specifying both the Culture & UI Culture settings ?

Comment: Yes, I've set the value of both to en-GB.

Comment: Only other thing I can think is that something is sitting between your client & server (a proxy perhaps) that's modifying the requests.

can you put a tool like fiddler/wireshark on the server to see the actual HTTP Request coming in and to make sure it isn't requesting en-US.

Alternatively can you interact with the site on the server itself (i.e. from Localhost) to see if it's still broken there ?

Comment: UICulture should be only "en".

Comment: @Eoin Thanks for the time. It seems that changing the form to POST fixed the problem.

Comment: Doh!. Of course... data in the URI is culture invariant. here's some information on why. 

http://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/05/14/localization-of-dates-in-asp-net-mvc/

Even that url itself is a good example. you need the date component to have the same behaviour for en-GB users as for en-US users.

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause is the system setting of date/time format is set to US. You can check that in Region and Language in Control Panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your server probably runs as a different culture. If you only run one project on your server, you can change its culture like Eoin Campbell just suggested

but if your server runs other projects that are culture aware, you can just force the thread of your project into UK mode like so:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB")
```

Without affecting all other things running on the server

Comment: shouldn't the globalization section of web.config do this? I'd rather not have to change code just to make the app work on a specific server if at all possible.

Comment: well yes, it *should* but it seems like that's not working for some reason... So I thought maybe its overruled somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```